# .net converting image jpg to jp2 using magick.net

Tags: .net, image

I have ZERO experience with converting images. The web app I am working on uploads a picture and converts the jpeg image to a jp2 image.I get an error when i try to write the image. The error is: permission denied, unable to open the image.

1. How to solve the error?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

.net code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using System.IO;
    public class fileUploader : IHttpHandler {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            try
            {
                string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/");
                string[] files;
                int numFiles;
                files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
                numFiles = files.Length;
                numFiles = numFiles + 1;
                string str_image = "";

                foreach (string s in context.Request.Files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[s];
                    string fileName = file.FileName;
                    string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                    {
                        fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                        str_image = "MyPHOTO_" + numFiles.ToString() + fileExtension;
                        string pathToSave_100 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/") + str_image;
                        file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100);
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(pathToSave_100))
{
  image.Format = Magick.jp2
  image.Write(pathToSave_100); //get error here: 
}
                    }
                }
                //  database record update logic here  ()

                context.Response.Write(str_image);
            }
            catch (Exception ac) 
            { 

            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable {
            get {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A web site typically runs under a special user account that won't have all the same permissions as your own account. Check that this special account has write permissions to your `~/MediaUploader/` path.

Comment: how would I identify this 'special account'? Are there any resources that you can point me at?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the way how and where you host website, you may not have permissions to write to folder you are trying to write.

Please try if you can use a folder below ~/App_Data. By convention this place in most cased can be used to store files that needs write access in ASP .NET, so that may be writeable by default with your production system.

Comment: its on a private server... the app will be on a windows 2012 server

Comment: Then you can go to folder you are going to use and assign write permissions to IIS